# Can this php code be shorter?

Tags: php, text-files

I have this primitive and rather long code to enable users to create/open (if already exists) text files..
it does the job for me but I wonder if it can be shorter.

the idea of it just like the http://etherpad.org/ website where people can create /save/open text files without registration, people are supposed to reach their files by using unique filename(s).

### index.php file

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);
</script>


<?php

if (isset($_GET['filename']))
    {
    $ourfile = trim($_GET['filename']) . ".html";
    }

if (!isset($_POST['filename']))
    { ?>

<form action="index.php" METHOD="POST">

<input type=text name="filename" required>

<input type=submit value="open/create">
</form>

<?php
    }
  else
    {
    $ourfile = trim($_POST['filename']) . ".html";
    }

if (!empty($ourfile) && file_exists($ourfile))
    {
    $file_handle = fopen($ourfile, "r");
    $file_content = fread($file_handle, filesize($ourfile));
    fclose($file_handle);
?>
<form action="save.php" METHOD="POST">

<input type=hidden name="filename" value = "<?php
    echo $ourfile; ?>">
<textarea rows=24 cols=80 maxlength=1000 name=notes>
<?php
    echo $file_content; ?>
</textarea>
<input type=submit value="save">
</form>
<?php
    }
  else
    {
    if (!empty($ourfile))
        {
        $file_handle = fopen(trim($ourfile) , "w");
        fwrite($file_handle, "Start editing " . $ourfile);
        fclose($file_handle);
        $ourfile = str_replace(".html", "", $ourfile);
        header("location:index.php?filename=$ourfile");
        }
    }

?>
```

---

save.php file

### this proceeding part of "\xEF\xBB\xBF" is to maintain the utf language (Arabic).

```
<?php


    $ourfile = $_POST['filename'];

$file_handle = fopen($ourfile,"w");
     fwrite($file_handle,"\xEF\xBB\xBF".$_POST['notes']);
    fclose($file_handle);

header("location:$ourfile");

?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although I understand this question is *off-topic* (a code review rather than an objective problem), I skimmed over this code anyway.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['filename'])) {
        $ourfile = trim($_GET['filename']) . ".html";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['filename'])) { ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="filename" required>
        <input type="submit" value="open/create">
    </form>
<?php } else { $ourfile = trim($_POST['filename']) . ".html"; }
    if (file_exists($ourfile)) {
        $file_handle = fopen($ourfile, "r");
        $file_content = fread($file_handle, filesize($ourfile));
        fclose($file_handle); ?>
    <form action="save.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php echo $ourfile; ?>">
        <textarea rows=24 cols=80 maxlength=1000 name="notes"><?php echo $file_content; ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </form>
<?php } else {
    if (!empty($ourfile)) {
        $file_handle = fopen(trim($ourfile) , "w");
        fwrite($file_handle, "Start editing " . $ourfile);
        fclose($file_handle);
        $ourfile = str_replace(".html", "", $ourfile);
        header("Location: index.php?filename=" . $ourfile);
    }
} ?>
```

All white space (spaces, TABs, newlines), in most programming languages is completely arbitrary. That is, you can use as much or as little white space as you want, and it won't affect compilation or execution. I took a few things out of your code that were unnecessary, and made some minor adjustments to the HTML (no quotes where there should have been, etc.).

Just apply the same technique to your other file. Get rid of blank lines, uneven indentation. Keep the indentation consistent though, otherwise you code will be a mess and hard to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this part was needed => if (isset($ourfile) && file_exists($ourfile)) {